# flutter, after push a native viewController from flutter, is this possible display more content above native viewController with flutter again?

Tags: flutter

I have a native viewController which implement from a framework, I can't directly change it into flutter view.

So I think I can:

1. Display the UI in `native ViewController`(a 3rd party native `video player`) from `flutter main app`.
2. Then I need display some `extra content`(for example `user avatar`, some `text message` and so on) `above/on native ViewController`
3. But I would prefer implement this extra content with `flutter`, if it's possible?

Is this good approach ? If not, then I think have to do the things bellow:

1. Display the UI in `native ViewController(a video player)` from flutter main app.
2. Then display some `extra content with native code`.

PS: why I can't change the native VideController into flutter ? it's because it integration with a native video player which integration cache logic and I can't change the source code in that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'native' in term native ViewController?

Comment: @mico yes, a native UIViewControler

Comment: @JerryZhou You can use native code in the flutter app by developing plugins. But you have to make some code for integration. Refer to this link https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages. In the same way, you can also add a new package to existing flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

According to [1] it is fine to have some component native, because there just are not all features in new cross platform frameworks like flutter.

According to [2] you could use Decorators from Container to show content in layers, taken that you can show the native content **embedded** to the Flutter code. In that case, definitely use approach 1.

However, I could only find platform-channels type of solution from Flutter documentation [4] to do native code execution and there it states for example this:

> To comply with channels’ UI thread requirement, you may need to **jump** from a background thread to Android’s UI thread to execute a channel method.

and in other post [3] on platform-channels:

> When the user clicks back I want to **navigate back** to flutter [..]

Both imply everything that is native happens in native thread and view, so I don't see possibility other than your second approach, where all is native.

So, all depends how you fit the native element to Flutter. If you embed, use Flutter for overlays, otherwise do all native. I think good way to measure this is that if you see anything from Flutter generated code when inside the native viewer, you have chances to overlay, otherwise just go native.

---

[1] [Open native UIViewController in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290461/open-native-uiviewcontroller-in-flutter/56355437)

[2] https://cogitas.net/overlay-text-icon-image-flutter/

[3] [How to change the root view controller back to flutter from native iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889520/how-to-change-the-root-view-controller-back-to-flutter-from-native-ios)

[4] https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: sorry fo delay, it's a little much for me, let me check it through first.